# FILE* assignment does not work

Tags: c, file-io

im facing a bit of a problem recently. i want to implement my own fopen function for error checking purposes.

Heres the relevant code so far:

```
enum _Errorcode_ openFile( const char * c_str_filename, const char * c_str_mode, FILE* the_file )
{
    the_file = fopen( c_str_filename, c_str_mode );

    if( the_file == NULL )
    {
        return FILE_IO_ERROR;
    }

    else
    {
        return OK;
    }
}
```

i call the function like this:

```
FILE * oFile = NULL;
...
ErrorCode = openFile( "myfile.txt", "r", oFile );
```

If i check the pointer addr of oFile afterwards, its still pointing to NULL.
The wird thing is, my function returend OK, and no failure. why is that so?

The file exists, if i call the fopen() function just so, everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C passes parameters by value, so you assign to a copy of oFile, that's why you don't see the change outside of `openFile()`.

Pass a pointer to it, like so:

```
enum _Errorcode_ openFile( const char * c_str_filename, const char * c_str_mode, FILE** the_file )
{
  *the_file = fopen( c_str_filename, c_str_mode );

  if( *the_file == NULL )
  {
    return FILE_IO_ERROR;
  }
  else
  {
    return OK;
  } 
}
....
FILE * oFile = NULL;
...
ErrorCode = openFile( "myfile.txt", "r", &oFile );
```

Comment: thanks a lot, both of you for the VERY quick answer. the thing is, even IN the function, the pointer after the fopen IS NULL, but the if still fails. strange. i will mark your answer as correct since you were first. But thanks to binyamin too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since C is always pass-by-value, e.g. the parameter that is passed to the function is a copy of the original variable, you need to pass a pointer to the `FILE *`:

```
enum _Errorcode_ openFile( const char * c_str_filename, const char * c_str_mode, 
                           FILE** the_file )
{
    *the_file = fopen( c_str_filename, c_str_mode );
    if( *the_file == NULL ) {   return FILE_IO_ERROR; }
    else {  return OK; }
}
```